# Verifying formulas for reflection, rotation, and translation in the Complex plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

1) If $T_a : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ is given by $T_a(z) = z + a$ then $T^{−1} _a
(z) = z − a = T_{−a}(z)$ for some fixed $a ∈ \Bbb C$.

2) If $ρ_θ : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ is given by $ρ_θ(z) = e^{iθ}z + a$ then $ρ^{−1}_θ(z) = e^{−iθ}(z − a)$ for some fixed $a ∈ \Bbb C$.

3) If $τ : \Bbb C → \Bbb C$ is given by $τ (z) = e^{iθ}z + a$ then $τ^{−1}(z) = e
^{−iθ}(z − a)$ for some fixed $a ∈ \Bbb C$.

My book has asked me to verify that these are true. I'm having trouble figuring out how to to do that. From what I understand, a function composed with it's inverse should yield the identity element.

So from that we have:

$T_a T^{−1} _a(z) = (z-a) + a = z$.

$ρ_θρ^{−1}_θ(z) = e^{iθ}(e^{−iθ}(z − a)) + a = z$

I'm not really sure how else to proceed solving these. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You wrote the same thing for $\rho_{\theta}$ and $\tau$. Are you sure there is not a mistake ?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. You should technically verify that the other order of composition yields the identity too, i.e., $f \circ g = \text{id} = g \circ f$, or at least state it.

Comment: What you have done is exactly how to verify that they are true (see comment above for a missing detail). You can also explain the formula geometrically: $ze^{i\theta} + a$ is a rotation by $\theta$ followed by a translation by $a$. The inverse formula is then a translation by $-a$ followed by a rotation by $-\theta$ which is exactly what the inverse formula says.

Comment: I actually copied and pasted it directly from the book. I did think it was odd as well.

Comment: @pjs36 So should I do both to ensure that it is valid? Also thank you.

Comment: @Winther Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nid Technically, yes, you *should* do both: Some functions only have left-inverses, some only have right-inverses, the invertible ones have both, and they're equal (like functions whose limits exist!).